# Problem XDEBUG + php

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I have a problem, I'm using Netbeans 8 to develop a tool with java 7. I installed XDEBUG but when I run the debug it shows me an error with the following message:
Unable to open web browser.
Not for breack-points.
If anyone can help me I appreciate it.

Comment: How did you install _xdebug_ ?

Comment: #apt-get install xdebug php5-xdebug
#apt-get install php-5-dev
#apt-get install xdebug

Comment: DId you edit the `php.ini` file with the required configurations ?

Comment: Yes Im Do, This only reference.
zend_extenssions = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so

Comment: These are needed: `xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 xdebug.remote_port=9000`

Comment: Please add these and let me know if it works so I can post an answer.

Comment: After you told me this I happened to look at the xdebug.so file opened and it is empty. Should that be empty?

Comment: Don't how _shared object files_ are used or how they should be, but I advice you don't open it for any reason. Just add those other configuration then test it...

Comment: Im resolve for question the simples forms, im update the apache2. 
ok

Comment: Add these configuration and test it `xdebug.remote_enable=1 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp xdebug.remote_mode=req xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 xdebug.remote_port=9000` and let me know

Comment: Is it now working with the added configurations, so I can add that as an answer?